# Cannot connect to X11 from service

Tags: c, linux, x11, xserver

I have written a daemon that connects to the X server and queries information periodically. I have configured the daemon to run on startup as a service, using `chkconfig`. It is set for run level 5. The `start` command for the init script runs the command `my_daemon &`.

When the daemon is running, however, it cannot connect to the X server display, even after several minutes. The command I use to connect is:

```
display = XOpenDisplay(NULL)
```

The script works fine when I just run `my_daemon &` manually from a terminal. So, how can I get it working as a startup service?

Comment: You probably have no DISPLAY environment variable when launching the daemon, but you would in your shell testing environment.

Comment: I tried adding a `export DISPLAY=:0.0` command in the init script, but it doesn't seem to help. Am I doing the right thing?

Comment: Okay I got it working. I had to use the command: `DISPLAY=:0 bash -c 'my_daemon &'`